# Do items in a std::map stay at the same address forever?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

Take the following simple program:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    string s;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f1 = { 42,21,11, "Hello world" };
    std::map<int, Foo> foomap;

    foomap[400] = f1;
    Foo* ptr = &foomap[400]; // cache a pointer to the element we just inserted.

    cout << ptr->x << " " << ptr->y << " " << ptr->z << " " << ptr->s << std::endl;

    // fill the map up with a bunch of other random items at random indices   
    for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
    {
        int i = rand();
        Foo f = { rand(), rand(), rand(), "Another string" };

        if (foomap.find(i) == foomap.end())
        {
            foomap[i] = f;
        }
    }

    Foo* ptr2 = &foomap[400];

    cout << "f1 insert location has " << ((ptr == ptr2) ? "not changed" : "changed") << std::endl;
    cout << ptr->x << " " << ptr->y << " " << ptr->z << " " << ptr->s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So the program above caches a pointer to an item in the map. Then adds a whole lot more items into the map, and then validates if the first inserted item has changed location.

I was somewhat surprised when I ran it. The cached pointer stays intact:

```
42 21 11 Hello world
f1 insert location has not changed
42 21 11 Hello world
```

I would have assumed that as the map grows with respect to the number of items in it, the implementation might move items around - just like std::vector absolutely does.

So my question is this: Are items inserted into a map guaranteed to be at the same address as long as it's not removed from the map or replaced?  Or is this implementation specific?

Comment: All the node-based containers work like this. Changes to the container simply adjust pointers - they don't move things around in memory.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - it this documented anywhere?

Comment: @NeilButterworth - what defines a "node based container". Clearly vector wouldn't qualify, but map would....

Comment: Any decent C++ textbook.

Comment: I have lots of decent C++ textbooks. Details like this aren't usually covered. :)

Comment: Ok - I just now see it on the Wikipedia page for associative containers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, insertion / emplacement operations on map never invalidate iterators or references to existing items.

> **26.2.6 Associative containers [associative.reqmts]**
>   9 The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the `erase` members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

Comment: By chance you cite a reference or doc that affirms this?

Comment: @selbie Added quote from standard